# Codeeval Challenge 230: Football, Answer Only Partially Correct

Tags: python-2.7

I am working on a relatively new challenge in CodeEval called 'Football.' The description is listed in the following link:
https://www.codeeval.com/open_challenges/230/

Inputs are lines of a file read by Python, and within each line there are lists separated by '|', with each list representing a country: the first being country "1", second being country "2", and so on.

> 1 2 3 4 | 3 1 | 4 1
>
> 19 11 | 19 21 23 | 31 39 29

Outputs are also lines in response to each line read from the file.

> 1:1,2,3; 2:1; 3:1,2; 4:1,3;
>
> 11:1; 19:1,2; 21:2; 23:2; 29:3; 31:3; 39:3;

so country 1 supports team 1, 2, and 3 as shown in the first line of output: `1:1,2,3`.

Below is my solution, and since I have no clue why the solution only works for the two sample cases lited in the description link, I'd like to ask anyone for comments and hints on how to correct my code. Thank you very much for your time and assistance ahead of time.

```
import sys

def football(string):
    countries = map(str.split, string.split('|'))
    teams = sorted(list(set([i[j] for i in countries for j in range(len(i))])))
    results = []
    for i in range(len(teams)):
        results.append([teams[i]+':'])
        for j in range(len(countries)):
            if teams[i] in countries[j]:
                results[i].append(str(j+1))
    for i in range(len(results)):
        results[i] = results[i][0]+','.join(results[i][1:])
    return '; '.join(results) + '; '
            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    lines = [line.rstrip() for line in open(sys.argv[1])]
    for line in lines:
        print football(line)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I solved it:

```
import sys

with open(sys.argv[1]) as test_cases:
    for test in test_cases:
        if test:
            team_supporters = {}
            for nation, nation_teams in enumerate(test.strip().split("|"), start=1):
                for team in map(int, nation_teams.split()):
                    team_supporters.setdefault(team, []).append(nation)
            print(*("{}:{};".format(team, ",".join(map(str, sorted(nations))))
                    for team, nations in sorted(team_supporters.items())))
```

The problem is not very complicated. We're given a mapping from nation (implicitly numbered by their order in the input) to a list of teams. We need to reverse that to create an output that maps from a team to a list of nations.

It seems natural to use a dictionary that maps in the same way as the desired output. We can use `enumerate` to give numbers to the nations as we iterate over them. The `setdefault` method of the dict adds empty lists to the dictionary as they are needed (using a `collections.defaultdict` instead of a regular dictionary would be another way to deal with this). We don't need to care about the order of the input, nor the order things are stored in the dictionary's inner lists.

The output we build using `str.format` calls and the default space separator of the `print` function. If the final semicolon wasn't desired, I'd have used `print("; ".join("{}:{}.format(...)))` instead. Since the output needs to be sorted by team at the top level, and by nation in the inner lists, we make some `sorted` calls where necessary.

Sorting the inner lists is probably not even be necessary, since the nations were processed in order, with their numbers derived from the order they had in the input line. Fortunately, Python's [Timsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) algorithm is very fast on already-sorted input, so even with a bit of unnecessary sorting, our code is still fast enough.

Comment: Hi Blckknght, thank you for your solution. It is indeed a better one than mine as the process is more straightforward. I also learned about new things like you can call the `enumerate` to start not at 0, and you can use `setdefault`. So what `team_supporters.setdefault(team, []).append(nation)` does is, if I'm understanding correctly: it searches for the `key` with value `team` to add the `nation`, but if the `team` key is not yet in the dictionary, then `setdefault` adds an empty list [] with `key` as the previously-non-existing new `team`? Thanks again!

Comment: Just played with setdefault a bit and confirmed it. Thanks again for the great tips!

Answer (score 1):

After deliberately failing an attempt to checkout the complete test input and my output, I found the problem. The line:

```
teams = sorted(list(set([i[j] for i in countries for j in range(len(i))])))
```

will make the output problematic in terms of sorting. For example here's a sample input:

```
10 20 | 43 23 | 27 | 25 | 11 1 12 43 | 33 18 3 43 41 | 31 3 45 4 36 | 25 29 | 1 19 39 | 39 12 16 28 30 37 | 32 | 11 10 7
```

and it produces the output:

```
1:5,9; 10:1,12; 11:5,12; 12:5,10; 16:10; 18:6; 19:9; 20:1; 23:2; 25:4,8; 27:3; 28:10; 29:8; 3:6,7; 30:10; 31:7; 32:11; 33:6; 36:7; 37:10; 39:9,10; 4:7; 41:6; 43:2,5,6; 45:7; 7:12;
```

But the challenge expects the output teams to be sorted by numbers in ascending order, which is not achieved by the above-mentioned code as the numbers are in string format, not integer format. Therefore the solution is simply adding a key to sort the teams list by ascending order for integer:

```
teams = sorted(list(set([i[j] for i in countries for j in range(len(i))])), key=lambda x:int(x))
```

With a small change in this line, the code passes through the tests. A sample output looks like:

```
1:5,9; 3:6,7; 4:7; 7:12; 10:1,12; 11:5,12; 12:5,10; 16:10; 18:6; 19:9; 20:1; 23:2; 25:4,8; 27:3; 28:10; 29:8; 30:10; 31:7; 32:11; 33:6; 36:7; 37:10; 39:9,10; 41:6; 43:2,5,6; 45:7;
```

**Please let me know if you have a better and more efficient solution to the challenge. I'd love to read better codes or great suggestions on improving my programming skills.**

Comment: Thanks for providing the test case and output! It helped me identify I was sorting my dictionary keys as strings instead of integers.

Comment: Hi Todd, you are welcome! It makes me happy that what I wrote could help someone else to solve the problem :)